# openssl: register a CA as an unprivileged user

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm in a situation where I have a Certificate Authority (CA) that I need to register with openssl, but no root access.  Even if I had root access, I don't think it would be right to register this at a system level because this is a development situation.

Is there any ability in openssl to have CA's registered at a user-level? I'm hoping for something like the `~/.ssh` directory, except for CA's.

Answer (score 1):

The `openssl` subcommands accept the `-CAfile` and `-CApath` options:

From the manpage:

```
-CAfile file
    Verify the signature on a CRL by looking up the issuing certificate
    in file.

-CApath directory
    Verify the signature on a CRL by looking up the issuing certificate
    in dir.  This directory must be a standard certificate directory,
    i.e. a hash of each subject name (using x509 -hash) should be
    linked to each certificate.
```

Comment: I guess my question was ambiguous, but I'm trying to solve this for the various tools which use the openssl system, i.e. `libssl`. I don't believe this relates to the `openssl` command.